# Can't authenticate with mongoDB from docker-compose service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, authentication, docker-compose

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to set up a docker-compose definition, where I have a mongoDB container, and a nodeJS container that connects to it.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  events-db:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: $SANDBOX_DB_USER
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $SANDBOX_DB_PASS
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: sandboxdb

  app:
    image: node:15.12.0
    user: node
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app:ro
    environment:
      MDB_CONNECTION: mongodb://$SANDBOX_DB_USER:$SANDBOX_DB_PASS@events-db:27017/sandboxdb
    command: node myapp
    depends_on:
      - events-db

volumes:
  db-volume:
```

Along with a `.env` file that declares the credentials (planning to use proper env variables when I deploy this to a production environment):

```
SANDBOX_DB_USER=myuser
SANDBOX_DB_PASS=myp4ss
```

Finally, my nodejs script, `myapp.js` is simply trying to connect, grab a reference to a collection, and insert a document:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

async function main () {
  console.log('Connecting')
  const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MDB_CONNECTION, {
    connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  await client.connect()
  const db = client.db()
  const events = db.collection('events')

  console.log('Inserting an event')
  await events.insertOne({
    type: 'foo',
    timestamp: new Date(),
  })

  console.log('Done.')
  process.exit(0)
}

if (require.main === module) {
  main()
}
```

### Result

When I run `docker-compose config` I see the following output, so I would expect it to work:

```
$ docker-compose config
services:
  app:
    command: node myapp
    depends_on:
      events-db:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      MDB_CONNECTION: mongodb://myuser:myp4ss@events-db:27017/sandboxdb
    image: node:15.12.0
    user: node
    volumes:
    - C:\workspace\dcsandbox:/home/node/app:ro
    working_dir: /home/node/app
  events-db:
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: sandboxdb
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: myp4ss
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: myuser
    image: mongo
    volumes:
    - db-volume:/data/db:rw
version: '3.9'
volumes:
  db-volume: {}
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up` I see that my node container is unable to connect to the mongoDB to insert an event:

```
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:36.793+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
app_1        | Connecting
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.811+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.27.0.3:34164","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.816+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.27.0.3:34164","client":"conn1","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.6.6"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.19.128-microsoft-standard"},"platform":"'Node.js v15.12.0, LE (unified)"}}}
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.820+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.27.0.3:34166","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.822+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.27.0.3:34166","client":"conn2","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.6.6"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"4.19.128-microsoft-standard"},"platform":"'Node.js v15.12.0, LE (unified)"}}}
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.822+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":"myuser@sandboxdb"}}
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.823+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"myuser","authenticationDatabase":"sandboxdb","client":"172.27.0.3:34166","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"sandboxdb\""}}
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.824+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","principalName":"myuser","authenticationDatabase":"sandboxdb","client":"172.27.0.3:34166","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"myuser\" for db \"sandboxdb\""}}
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.826+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.27.0.3:34164","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
app_1        | /home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268
app_1        |           callback(new MongoError(document));
app_1        |                    ^
app_1        |
app_1        | MongoError: Authentication failed.
app_1        |     at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
app_1        |     at MessageStream.emit (node:events:369:20)
app_1        |     at processIncomingData (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
app_1        |     at MessageStream._write (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
app_1        |     at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:395:12)
app_1        |     at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:340:10)
app_1        |     at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:750:22)
app_1        |     at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
app_1        |     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
app_1        |     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:288:9) {
app_1        |   ok: 0,
app_1        |   code: 18,
app_1        |   codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
app_1        | }
events-db_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-07T13:57:38.832+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.27.0.3:34166","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":0}}
dcsandbox_app_1 exited with code 1
```

I've put the full output at https://pastebin.com/uNyJ6tiy
and the example code at this repo: https://github.com/akatechis/example-docker-compose-mongo-node-auth

Comment: Try to write to console the connection string

Comment: When I log `process.env.MDB_CONNECTION` in my node script, I see the following output from docker-compose: `app_1        | Connecting to mongodb://myuser:myp4ss@events-db:27017/sandboxdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging, I managed to figure it out. The issue is that the `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` variables simply set the root user's credentials, and the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` simply sets the initial database for scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

By default, the root user is added to the `admin` database, so by removing the `/sandboxdb` part of the connection string, I was able to have my node app authenticate against the `admin` DB as the root user.

While this doesn't *quite* accomplish what I wanted initially (to create a separate, non-root user for my database, and use that to authenticate), I think this puts me on the right path to using an init script to set up the user accounts I want to have.